# Looping Array for element Id-javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to get the element ID of which is dynamic. Only the last digit changes as across the pages. For example `id="orange-UU-ID-XX"`, the ID is going to be between `"orange-UU-ID-01"` and `"orange-UU-ID-04"`.
I tried to put the values into and array,manually, then tried to compare against values of that array. if the ID is found then break.

- What am I doing wrong?.
- Is there is any other better,efficient method?

  ```
  var ary = ["orange-UU-ID-01", "orange-UU-ID-02", "orange-UU-ID-03", "orange-UU-ID-04"];
  var i = 0;
  var text = "";
  while (ary[i]) {
      text=text+ ary[i];
      i++;
  }
  if(document.getElementById("text")!="null"||document.getElementById("text")!="undefined")
  {
      window.alert(text);
  }
  ```

Comment: `getElementById` return _null_ or html element - it always return _true_ for this condition `!="null"` because here you compare object with string, and same with _"undefined"_. also your code try get html element with `id="text"` and not something else

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "orange-UU-ID-01";

var str_sub = str.substr(str.lastIndexOf("-")+1);
```

If the end delimiter is not always an underscore, then you could use regex:

```
var pat = /([0-9]{1,})$/;
var m = str.match(pat);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ids of all existing elements. One solution is ([fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/OriDrori/otpmgnp2/1/)):

```
var textElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[id^=orange-UU-ID-]'), 0);

textElements.forEach(function(el) {
    console.log(el.id);
});
```